# How to fix Xcode Simulator to stop makes mirror elements arranged

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have problem with Simulator, elements in Xcode change their position respect to Y axis. 
I rebuild project, restart my MacBook, change iphone type in Simulator, check Constraints, but nothing helped.

[back and next are reverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ktL.png)

[people buttons and x button turned symmetrically with respect to the Y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6MDN.png)

Comment: Your `Autolayour` constraints are probably flawed. Please include them in your question. Since the the UI elements that are on horizontally centered look correct, I am pretty sure the problem is with your constraints.

Comment: Check right to left languages support or constraint issue. I suggest to create another small project and test it there.